# Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have following entities with a many-to-many relationships.

[image]

i'm making a small playlist app where the entity named Entity is for the playlists and the songs entity is for the songs. at the moment i have a viewcontroller where you can add playlists to the Entity and a viewcontroller where you can add songs to the song entity. The problem is that all the videos are shown in every playlists. How can i hook this relationship up between these 2 entities?

Do i need to make a attribute in Songs which hold a playlist id? or how will the Entity know which song belong in which Entity object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to choose slightly different names for the entities
and relationships, in particular the *singular form* (Song, Playlist) for the entity
name, and the *plural form of the destination* (songs, playlists) for to-many relationships:

[image]

Now the objects are "hooked up" by setting the relationship between them.
Assume that you have a song and a playlist:

```
Song *songA;
Playlist *playlistB;
```

Now you can either call

```
[songA addPlaylistsObject:playlistB]; // (1)
```

or

```
[playlistB addSongsObject:songA]; // (2)
```

to establish a relationship between these two objects.
It does not matter whether which one you call because "songs" and "playlists"
are *inverse relationships*. `songA` is added to `playlistB.songs`,
and `playlistB` is added to `songA.playlists`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Check this 
This is picture of the answer! You will need to use a table to couple the to tables together.

Comment: the ID need to be unique before your answer will work. How can i do this?