# Create relationship between to entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a ViewController with playlists which is saved in a NSMutableArray. I pass the selected object to the SecondViewController using Singleton.

```
 optionsSingle.selectedRowNow = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in the SecondViewController, i add songs. How can i associate the optionsSingle.selectedRowNow which is passed to the SecondViewController with the saved song? I would appreciate with a code snippet/sample since i've been struggling with this for hours and haven't been able to find something useful on the internet.

add songs method:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject;
newManagedObject = (Songs*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSDate *today= [NSDate date];

[newManagedObject setValue:video.author forKey:@"author"];
[newManagedObject setValue:video.videoid forKey:@"link"];
[newManagedObject setValue:video.title forKey:@"songName"];
[newManagedObject setValue:today forKey:@"created"];
```

Entities

songs.h

```
@class Playlists;

@interface Songs : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * author;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * created;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * link;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * songName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;
@end

@interface Songs (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addSongsObject:(Playlists *)value;
- (void)removeSongsObject:(Playlists *)value;
- (void)addSongs:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSongs:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

playlists.h

```
@class Songs;

@interface Playlists : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * playlistName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *list;
@end

@interface Playlists (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addListObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)removeListObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)addList:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeList:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Comment: Note that your naming of the relationships is "unconventional" and might be the reason for your confusion (compare my suggestion in response to your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149021/1187415). The relationship from "Song" to "Playlist" should be called "lists" or "playlist", but not "songs". The the relationship from "Playlist" to "Song" should be called "songs", but not "list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[optionsSingle.selectedRowNow addListObject:newManagedObject];
```

this gets the playlist from the 'singleton' and adds the relationship to the song (appends to whatever songs are currently in the relationship).

Comment: After you did that, it won't be saved yet to the database. You'll need to call `save:` on your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Comment: How come i i cant use addSongsObject? I have imported the 2 entities?

Comment: I got the wrong method name. Your names are really bad... `Playlist` entity should have `songs` and `Song` entity should have `playlists` as the relationship names.